# jquery sort ul element by the size of their children

Tags: jquery, list, function, sorting, children

Just a short question about sorting HTML element.

If have more than 10 unordered list with different sizes of children.
Is their an easy way to re-order them?

HTML examle:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is what I want to have:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fairly easy with vanilla `.sort()`.

- Get elements
- Detach them
- Sort them
- Add them back to the DOM

**JavaScript**

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

// Get children and detach
var children = $wrapper.children().detach();

// Sort them
children.sort(function(a, b) {
    // Compare amount of children
    return $(a).children().length - $(b).children().length;
});

// Add them back
$wrapper.append(children);
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xavmu/).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Tims answer, you can wrap this functionality in a jQuery function like this.

```
$.fn.sortChildren = function(sortCb){
  this.children().detach().sort(sortCb).appendTo(this);
};
```

And then you can use it like this which improves the readability and reusability.

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

// Sort them
$wrapper.sortChildren(function(a, b) {
    // Compare amount of children
    return $(a).children().length - $(b).children().length;
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xavmu/8/)